# Is account ID/Alias the same for all IAM users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

In AWS, is account ID/Alias the same for all IAM users? My guess is that all IAM users created with a root account share the same account ID/Alias.

Comment: Yes, the same across all IAM principals.

Comment: What is the actual problem that you're seeing that prompted this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Your AWS account identifiers - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html):

> AWS assigns the following unique identifiers to each AWS account:
>
> **AWS account ID**
> A 12-digit number, such as `123456789012`, that uniquely identifies an AWS account. Many AWS resources include the account ID in their Amazon Resource Names (ARNs). The account ID portion distinguishes resources in one account from the resources in another account. If you are an IAM user, you can sign in to the AWS Management Console using either the account ID or account alias.